# In python, is there a simple way to connect to a mysql database that doesn't require root access?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm writing a script to parse some text files, and insert the data that they contain into a mysql database. I don't have root access on the server that this script will run on. I've been looking at [mysql-python](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/), but it requires a bunch of dependencies that I don't have available. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: "don't have available"?  Are you prevented from installing the things you need?

Comment: Have you tried using easy_install?

Comment: @S.Lott, @David: Ah, I figured it out. I just needed to create a directory "~/lib/python2.6/site-packages", put it in my PYTHONPATH, and install with "prefix='/home/[myusername]'". I feel kind of silly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the [MySQL Python Connector](https://launchpad.net/myconnpy), a MySQL DB-API adapter that does not use the C client library but rather reimplements the MySQL protocol completely in pure Python (compatible with Python 2.5 to 2.7, as well a 3.1).

To install C-coded extensions to Python you generally need root access (though the server you're using might have arranged things differently, that's not all that likely).  But with a pure Python solution you can simply upload the modules in question (e.g. those from the Connector I recommend) just as you're uploading those you write yourself, which (if you of course do have a valid userid and password for that MySQL database!-) might solve it for you.